# Canon Camera Connect to Iphone to Cloud to Mac Issue

Tags: iphone, canon

I just started using Canon Camera Connect with my PowerShot. I am connect via wifi to my Iphone.  The photos move well to the phone and then to the Icloud.  I then did a usb transfer to my MacBook Pro and they were there.  Then to clear space on my camera I deleted (having already seen them on my Laptop).  When I deleted them from my camera they are now gone from everywhere.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please describe your iCloud Photo settings and how did you transferred your pictures via USB.

Answer (score 1):

If you have iCloud Photo Library activated, all changes are synced between all connected parties —deleting in one device deletes in all devices. Same will happen if you erased them from your Photo Stream although that would probably leave a copy on your Camera Roll (unless you erased iPhone originals when importing via USB and had only the Photo Stream copy left).

In any case, you can still look for your pictures in the "Recently Deleted" album; manually deleted pictures *should* be there but I couldn't find the Photo Stream deleted picture on it and I don't know if they are saved there when batch removed after importing via USB.